# "I have almost cried to pieces..."

Tags: meaning, grammar

I saw this sentence from [BBC Learning English.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/lower-intermediate/unit-7/session-3)

> I have almost cried to pieces.

What's the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: It's a semi-idiom simply meaning that you sob uncontrollably.

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/lower-intermediate/unit-7/session-3 seems to suggest it was written by a Norwegian girl, so may not be quite standard English.  Falling apart or falling to pieces are common descriptions for uncontrollable emotion.

Comment: @Henry I would say that it's definitely not standard English. There are one or two other slightly non-standard phrases in her account. I'm no criticising, her English was much better than my Norwegian!